# PyOpenCL Ubuntu Nvidia - Platform Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, pyopencl

PyOpenCL cannot access my Nvidia device after installing with the Ubuntu `python-pyopencl` package.  This method of installing PyOpenCL used to work with the same hardware and the same version of Ubuntu (14.10).

When I run `pyopencl.get_platforms()` the error message is:

```
LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: platform not found khr
```

I have tried different drivers, different package combinations, and a fresh install of the OS.

How do I make PyOpenCl install on Ubuntu for an Nvidia card?

**Update 1**

After a fresh install of the OS, `get_platforms()` shows two platforms: AMD and Intel (beignet). Nvidia still does not work.

**Update 2**

After trying a few more things at http://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo, the `python-pyopencl` package now throws an error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

python-pyopencl: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.0-6ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libopencl-1.1-1 but it is a virtual package
                 Depends: libopencl-1.2-1 but it is a virtual package
                 Depends: python-numpy (>= 1:1.8.0) but 1:1.8.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: python-numpy-abi9 but it is a virtual package
                 Depends: python (< 2.8) but 2.7.6-2 is to be installed
                 Depends: python-pytools (>= 2013.5.2) but 2014.2.1-1 is to be installed
```

Comment: Which nvidia graphics card driver are you using? I think Ubuntu uses the 'nouveau' open source driver by default, and I'm not sure that has opencl support. You can find out the driver by looking at /var/log/Xorg.0.log, where there will be a line like 'Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/ ...'

Comment: Right now I have the Nvidia 331-updates driver installed

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It looks like nvidia-libopencl1-346 (the driver I'm using) conflicts with something in the pyopencl dependency tree.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have correct permissions on /dev/nvidia*, which can only be accessed as root by default. Alternatively just run with sudo.

Comment: This answer helped me find the solution - I didn't have the correct permissions on the *script itself* that I was running. What solved this for me was to enter `sudo chmod u+x myscript.py`

Answer (score 1):

Try running your python script as root. If `cl.get_platforms()` does not throw any errors under root, then your user does not have sufficient privilege to perform the action. To solve this, install `nvidia-modprobe` package:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe
```

For further explanation, you can [read this blog](http://blog.linux4us.org/2015/05/30/how-to-solve-pyopencl-clgetplatformids-failed/).

Answer (score 0):

This command solved the issue for me on Ubuntu (Intel Graphic Card)

```
    sudo apt-get install opencl-headers
```